# How to retrieve the parent category images in Topmenu in magento?

Tags: magento, zend-framework, menu, magento-1.7, categories

In **magento** how to retrieve the **parent category images** in **Topmenu**. I have to show the parent category images , when click or mouse over the respected parent menu. I have try the below mentioned code, but i got all the category images. if i display in front end it all show under the respected menus. Can any guide me how to show correct images? My magento version is 1.7.0.2.

$categoryData = array(

```
            'name' => $category->getName(),
            'id' => $nodeId,
            'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
            'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
            'links' => $cat->getData('links'),
            'image' => $cat->getImageUrl('image'),
            'thumbnail' => $cat->getThumbnail(),
            'getLevel' => $category->getLevel()
        );
```

I want to use **thumbnail** image to show. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got solution for this and share the answer below. I can use the '**getLevel**' attribute to find the positions of the all menus. Then i find out the parent menus and show the respected image in the Topmenu.

It is added in the Model file. (/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php)

**Function Name:** _addCategoriesToMenu

```
$categoryData = array(

                'name' => $category->getName(),
                'id' => $nodeId,
                'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
                'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
                'links' => $cat->getData('links'),
                'image' => $cat->getImageUrl('image'),
                'thumbnail' => $cat->getThumbnail(),
                'getLevel' => $category->getLevel()
            );
```

It is add in the Html folder. (app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php)

**Function Name:** _getHtml

```
$parentLevels = $child->getLevel();

        if($parentLevels == 0) 
        {

            $urls = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$child->getData('thumbnail');

            $html .= '<img src="'.$urls.'" />';
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution is for Magento -1.8.*

In Model file. (/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php)

Update following code in Function Name: _addCategoriesToMenu

```
      $categoryData = array( 
            'name' => $category->getName(),
            'id' => $nodeId,
            'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
            'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
            'thumbnail' => Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getThumbnail()

        );
```

Then go into Html folder. (app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php)

Update the following line of code at line 128 in

Function name: _getHtml

```
        if($childLevel < 1 ){
            $urls = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$child->getData('thumbnail');
            $img = '<img src="'.$urls.'" />';
        }

        $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
        $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
            . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . ' </span> '.$img.' </a>';
```

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use ->load() in that function as it will be looping over and over.